# Remove default fade transition on JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova, mobile, transition

I'm developing a mobile app with Phonegap using Jquery Mobile. First I tried to normally add a transition to a  <  a  > tag using:

```
    <a href="#page2" data-transition="slide">Page 2</a>
```

just like it's explained on JQuery Mobile documentation, but I noticed that my page was doing a fading animation before actually doing the slide, and of course it looked horrible. After that happened I thought it was because there's a default animation so I looked for ways to remove it, and I found this:

```
    <script>
        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
        $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
        });
    </script>
```

But it still isn't working. I also tried to change the default transition to slide but it didn't work either. Thanks for your time, any ideas?

Comment: you should place `mobileinit` after jQuery.js and before jQuer-Mobile.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ordering of the mobileinit handler is important. It must go between your jQuery main file and the jQuery Mobile file

```
<!-- jQuery.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Place after jQuery.js but before jQueryMobile.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/app.js"></script>

<!-- jQueryMobile.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
```